# Lecture notes on Invariant theory of finite groups

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am looking for a book or lecture notes on invariant theory of finite groups. I am a beginner in this subject. Any basic references or lecture notes will be very helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at the standard books with "Invariant Theory" in their title? It will be helpful to answerers to know what you have already considered. The wikipedia page on the subject lists several great texts (among which is H. Kraft and C. Procesi's  *Classical Invariant Theory, a Primer*, which is very nice), and googling brings up a surprising number of notes on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of survey papers are [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1997-34-03/S0273-0979-97-00724-6/S0273-0979-97-00724-6.pdf) and [here](http://dedekind.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/38.pdf). There is also a [book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=SURV-94-S) by Mara Neusel and Larry Smith.